# Ruby on Rails <%= %> within a <%= link_to %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new with Ruby on Rails. I'm following a guide using haml. I don't like haml so I've skipped using that. The problem is that I'm trying to have my `<h2><%= forumthread.title %></h2>` link to the forumthread_path.

With haml its set to be: `%h2= link_to forumthread.title, forumthread_path`

How can I achieve the same result without haml?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just want this:

```
<h2><%= link_to forumthread.title, forumthread_path(forumthread) %></h2>
```

Which will generate the same thing as:

```
<h2><a href="<%= forumthread_path(forumthread) %>"><%= forumthread.title %></a></h2>
```

See the [`link_to` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), the first argument is the 'title' for the link, and the second is the path for the link.

Comment: the problem is I am getting a No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"forumthreads"} missing required keys: [:id]. Strangely it does seem to work using haml.

Comment: @jacobhed Are you trying to link to a specific forum thread, or to a list of forum threads?

Comment: Please send the output of rake routes for this action.

Comment: a specific forum thread. I'm looping through all the forum threads on the index page with <% @forumthreads.each do |forumthread| %>

Comment: @jacobhed In that case you need to pass the `forumthread` to the path helper. Does the edit above work for you?

Comment: @Undo, your edit worked! Thanks alot! Been struggling with this for a while. I'll mark it as the answer!

Comment: @jacobhed No problem - I didn't know HAML did that automatically.